# Mongoose populate function not returning array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want populate to return array of object, if we takeout populate it is returning category with array of id in

```
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    products:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
        ref:'Product'
    }]
})

autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection)
mongoose.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin,'Categories')
export default mongoose.model('Categories', categorySchema)
```

one Category has number of products

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    category:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
        ref:'Category'
    }
})


autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection)
mongoose.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Products')

export default mongoose.model('Products',productSchema)
```

```
export const getProductsByCat = async (req, res)=>
{
     try{
         const result1= await Category.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        console.log(result1)
```

this is the result
{ products: [ 24, 27, 28 ], _id: 3, name: 'Non-Vegetables', __v: 5 }

but when i apply populate function, then no result

```
        const products = await Category.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).populate('products')      
         console.log(products )
     }catch(error)
     {
         res.status(404).json({message:error.message})
     }
}
```

i want this result

```
{ products:[ { id:24, productName: 'eggs', price:100}, { id:27, productName: 'chicken', price:200},{ id:28, productName: 'fish', price:400}], _id: 3, name: 'Non-Vegetables', __v: 5 }
```

Comment: What does "no result" mean? Is the products array empty?

Comment: its is not returning anything, i want  it to return array of objects containing full details
below is the result which i want
Ex:-{ products[ { id:24, productName: 'eggs', price:100}, { id:27, productName: 'chicken', price:200},{ id:28, productName: 'fish', price:400}], _id: 3,  name: 'Non-Vegetables', __v: 5 }